# vmware player unable to start services in kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation, vmware, vmware-player

```
my environment:
kubuntu : 3.2.0-generic-pae
vmware player: VMware-Player-4.0.4-744019.i386.bundle
```

---

And i have been installed it.

```
$sh VMware-Player-4.0.4-744019.i386.bundle
```

---

I have a problem, when i launch "menu->system->VMware Player"

it launch a window and start compiling:

```
        [ok] Virtual Machine Monitor
    [failed] Virtual Network Device
        [ok] VMware Blocking Filesystem
        [ok] Virtual Machine Communication Interface
        [ok] VMCI Sockets

[result fail]Starting Vmare Services
           See log file /tmp/vmware-root/modconfig-2722.log for detail
```

---

from log file:

```
   [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings":
   No such file or directory.
   [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config":
   No such file or directory.
   [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences"
   No such file or directory.

  Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
  Failed to compile module vmnet!
```

---

Could some people tell me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that there are no linux headers installed on your machine, that is why it is impossible to build the `vmnet` module. You must install headers and then try once again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've had the same problem this evening when upgrading from 4.0.3 to 4.0.4. What I've found to work is to first download the patch from this VMWare community thread - http://communities.vmware.com/thread/344213

Unzip it and then open the patch-modules_3.2.0.sh in gedit. There will be three lines at the top that read:

`fpatch=vmware3.2.0.patch

vmreqver=8.0.2

plreqver=4.0.2`

You have to change the `plreqver=4.0.2` to `plreqver=4.0.4`

Then, open your terminal and run

`sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh`

As a side note, keep that file handy, because I found that I had to do the same thing when upgrading from 4.0.2 to 4.0.3 in Ubuntu 12.04. However, when you try the same again in the next upgrade (e.g. change the plreqver to 4.0.5 and run the script), it will say that the file is already patched and it won't work.

To get around this, you need to go to the "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/" folder, find the hidden file called ".patched", and delete it (easiest option is to "sudo nautilus" in terminal and hunt through the folder structure). Then it thinks that it hasn't been patched and does the process again.

Hope this gets your VMWare back up and running.